# Firefox 4 rendering difference using position:relative and top / margin-top?

Tags: html, css, firefox, browser

Below is a simplified code snippet that shows my problem.

I have a box with 3 pieces of information and they should be lined out correctly, but apparently in FireFox 4 the information is lined out lower that should be. Where does this difference come from and how should I solve this? Am I using the wrong methods for displaying the info perhaps?
I put red borders around the divs so you can visualize it better.

You can see it here: http://www.sharpsignal.com/test.html

EDIT: To clarify: in FF4 the bottom red box aligns with the boxwrap box, in other browsers there is still space between the 2, why does FF4 render this different and how can I fix it so its the same in all browsers?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>

<style type="text/css">

.boxwrap{
    border: 1px solid #666;
    width:120px;
    height:54px;
    font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#444;
}

.boxcontenttop{
    position:relative;
    left:10px;
    top:4px;
    font-size:9px;
    text-align:left;
    border:1px solid #DD0000;
}

.boxcontentmain{
    position:relative;
    right:10px;
    top:5px;
    text-align:right;
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:bold;
    border:1px solid #DD0000;
}

.boxcontentextra{
    margin-top: 7px;
    text-align: center;
    color:#888;
    font-size:10px;
    border:1px solid #DD0000;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="boxwrap">
    <div class="boxcontenttop">top info</div>
    <div class="boxcontentmain">Main content</div>
    <div class="boxcontentextra">Extra Info</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `left` and `right` is causing them to shift in the boxes.

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UPuCJ/1/) with red boxes aligned.

If you want vertical alignment, you'll need to position the values evenly based on the offset from the top.  [Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UPuCJ/2/)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However what I meant was the distance to the top is different in FF4 than in other browsers. As you check the example, or your live examples, you notice that the red border of the bottom box aligns with the bottom border of the boxwrap. In other browsers there still is a little space in between. I want that exact amount of pixels of space in between but firefox places it lower and I am not sure why or how to get it the same as in the other browsers/versions

Comment: No-one with an explanation for this? I guess I will replace it with a table for now.